# I'm trying to make a mini calculator and i'm a beginner

Tags: python

I want to make a python program for a mini calculator , i'm just starting to learn python and i don't really know what i'm doing.

```py
number1 = (input("first number:"))
number2 = (input("second number:"))
number3 = (input("do you want to add another number?"))

print("choose - / +")
something = input()

if number3 <= 0 and something == "+":
    print(str(number1) + "+" + str(number2) + "=" + number1 + + number2)

elif number3 <= 0 and something == "-":
    print(str(number1) + "-" + str(number2) + "=" + number1 - - number2)

elif number3 > 0 and something == "+":
    print(str(number1 )+ "+" + str(number2) + "+" + str(number3) + "=" + number1 + + number2 + + number3)

elif number3 > 0 and something == "-":
    print(str(number1 )+ "-" + str(number2) + "-" + str(number3) + "=" + number1 - - number2 - - number3)
```

I expected that i can choose a third number and choose between `+` / `-`

Comment: input() always gives a string so you do not need to convert to that;   but you do need to convert to a number before using it in arithmetic by using int(numberX) assuming you are using integers or float(numberX).

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of issues with your code.

input()s are always strings, if you need them to become something else (like integer numbers), you need to transform the input string into that, after checking whether the string actually represents a number. one way of doing that:

```
import string

number1 = (input("first number: "))
if set(number1).issubset(string.digits):
    number1 = int(number1)
else:
   print('I only eat integers!')
   return(0) # if inside a function
```

Another things is that you probably want to add the numbers as in calculate their sum or difference (which is why you need to convert the input). Currently you use '+' to concatenate strings. Now with changing the input to integers, you also need to adapt your print(), because you cannot mix the concatenate+ with the addition+.

For instance:

```
if number3 <= 0 and something == '+':
    print('{} + {} = {}'.format(number1, number2, number1+number2))
```

There are other ways to do that. Search for "format strings". The formatting lets to provide integers and does the transformation into something printable behind the scenes. If you want to stay closer to what you already have:

```
if number3 <= 0 and something == '+':
    print(str(number1) + " + " + str(number2) + " = " + str(number1+number2))
```

As a side-remark, you'll probably want to clarify that the input for number3 is not a yes/no (as the question in input suggests), but a number and that whether or not it is used for calculation depends on whether that number is positive or not.